# Asynchronous calls from a webapp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am writing an application which involves an asynchronous call to some other app. My app has to continuously send this request to the other app till I get a specific response. I can send this request in a 5 sec interval.

Using a thread won't be a good idea, what would be the best practice to implement this

When I get the specific response I have to store it in my app db.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is another way of doing this without at least somehow creating a new thread (or using an inactive one) to do this. However, there is something that you might be looking for. Spring provides task jobs which you can use to send a request every 5 seconds.

To do this by annotations, you must first add this namespace to your config.xml

```
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
```

Then add this definition:

```
<task:annotation-driven>
```

Now finally, you can just add this simple annotation to a method that will execute the request to your other server

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000) //time in milliseconds
```

More information on this can be found on this [site](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/23/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the control of the new treads and when those thread request must die you can use Spring async.https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

If you want an extra control you can use DeferredResult of Spring as well
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/deferredresult-asynchronous-processing-in-spring-mvc.html 
This last one will works as Future objects.